# Is it worth buying a SLR?

Tags: dslr, film, slr, digital-vs-film, digital

Is it worth buying a film camera? I have a DSLR but I also want to have an experience in using a SLR. I want a fully manual camera. DSLR cameras has manual mode but I think it's different  from a SLR. I like working with my hands so I think having a SLR won't be a problem. I'm thinking of these three cameras Nikon FM10, Pentax MG or a Canon AE-1. Are these good cameras? What SLR cameras would you recommend for a student like myself? Thanks

Comment: Id suggest that its not worth investing in used 35mm kit if you have a reasonable DSLR. 
HOWEVER - I have a Nikon D800 and wanted to play with film, so i bought a medium format camera (Hasselblad 503)
There is "Something" about the 6x6 images through the Zeiss lenses......

Comment: Given that you can get an old SLR with an unexciting but decent prime lens for the cost of a dinner for two at a budget bistro - eg http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/PRAKTICA-BMS-ELECTRONIC-35mm-CAMERA-WITH-PENTACON-50mm-1-1-8-LENS-/171148190315 - you might as well give it a go. If you don't like it, you can always sell it on again and get a good fraction of the money back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably answered many times, so only my short opinion: My film cameras are collecting dust in the corner. They are great tools and fancy and stuff, but compared to digital process, the work needed to have good print is much higher.

On the other hand - I enjoy producing something with my own hands, which means I can use only the B/W process. So I take the film out of camera, choose and mix developer, develop and pray that I do not screw anything, enjoy the smell and view of fresh negative. Once in a time occupy a bathroom, put in enlarger, remove dust, mix chemicals, switch on red bulb and spend all day with stinky air in bad light conditions. At the and, have nice paper prints, A4 sized, hand made, with stunning blacks, crispy contrast, beautiful motives... put in album and enjoy.

If you do have the same attitude and don't mind spending all day to get 4 prints, go for it. If buying carefully (http://fomaobchod.cz/), the chemicals: Film developing 7 EUR, Paper developing 7 EUR, Paper for playing (RC, 13x18cm) 20EUR/100 pcs, Paper for nice prints (Baryte, 24x30cm) 10EUR/10pcs. Tools, ebay, ~50 EUR, enlarger 50-100 EUR.